# Control size of the output of seqLogo?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, sequence-diagram

I am using the `seqLogo` package to draw some sequence Logos.  I need to make the logos wider, the default drawing makes the logos into square graphs.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the code from seqLogo:

```
> library(seqLogo)
> seqLogo
function (pwm, ic.scale = TRUE, xaxis = TRUE, yaxis = TRUE, xfontsize = 15, yfontsize = 15)
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    if (class(pwm) == "pwm") {
        pwm <- pwm@pwm
    }
    ...
}
<environment: namespace:seqLogo>
>
```

There are parameters in there that control rendering, which you could adjust by editing the function code. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8349123/19410) to learn about the `fix()` function.